# Get ID from Permission set

Tags: permission-sets

I have a problem and I need the Id of a permission set so that I can handle the problem through the workbench. How do I get the provider the 'ID' of the Permission set, specifically from PermissionApiOnlyUSer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below SOQL query to get the Id. This is supported from Workbench as well.

```
SELECT id,Name from PermissionSet Where Name='PermissionsetNameHere'
```

Comment: Thanks for help. It worked.